# Last two lines of .htaccess causing error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The last two lines of my .htaccess file are causing me to get a "Too many redirects" error.  If I delete one or the other of the last two lines, it works fine. However, I need both to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calc/


RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ec-(.*)$ eventcatvenue.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^e-(.*)-(.*)$ event-dates.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^e-(.*)-(.*)$ event-dates.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewevent.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: First, RewriteCond tests work only for the next RewriteRule. So you have to double the tests (RewriteCond RewriteCond RewriteRule, RewriteCond RewriteCond RewriteRule)

Comment: Secondly, You rewrite everything to viewpost.php.  And after that, everything to viewevent.php. So, it is not possible that it works. Think about what you want to rewrite, and why. And after you will find how.

Comment: I am attempting to create two blogs on a single site. So while viewpost.php collects data from one table in my database, viewevent.php collects data from a completely different table.  The RewriteRule enables the title slug to be at the end of the URL.

Comment: And by magic, the server guesses which one to use?

Comment: Any suggestions? I'm really not into magic.

Comment: As you did for others, add a letter at the beginning or use a subfolder